# CSS/HTML - wrapped long string inside a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, word-wrap

can I make a string inside a textarea to wrap on multiple lines? (to avoid the horizontal scrollbar)

Note that I have a very long string without any spaces (a encoded text), and css word-wrap properties don't seem to work on it...

Comment: You can apply html's soft-hyphen (`&shy;` if I recall correctly) to the string, this allows the word to be broken and hyphenated at that point, but which isn't visible *unless* necessary.

Comment: You shouldn't normally get a horizontal scrollbar at all. Opera is the only browser that does that by default.

Comment: you're right, I was using Opera...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is default and should work properly unless you specified the `wrap=on` or `wrap=true` (not sure which but think the first) attribute! what you need to force it is `wrap=hard`
you can however specify predetermined breaking points using the `&shy;` character somewhere in the word. it won't be visible, but break there.
you can also have a look a some function like http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php
you can also have a look at the following css settings:

```
overflow: scroll; 
overflow-y: scroll; 
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow:-moz-scrollbars-vertical;
```

Comment: It's `wrap="off"` that provokes the scrollbar in Firefox, IE and WebKit. This is documented at MSDN but is not a standard value for `wrap` in HTML5.

Comment: is `wrap` even a valid attribute any more? The W3 don't seem to think it exists, and even the non-affiliated, pause for shudder, W3schools don't mention it any more. Ah, oops. Html 5...sorry. I'll just get my coat... =/

Comment: its not :) his problem was opera (see above)